# PostgreSQL createdb throw fatal error

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm trying to create db on PostgreSQL on linux machine. And I use following command to create the DB.

> createdb mydbname;

This is throwing following error.

> createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  database
>   "postgres" does not exist

I'm new to PostgreSQL. Can you please guide me to go through this error? Simply I want to create a DB on psql.

Comment: Which linux distibution are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you dropped the `postgres` database. It's the default used for many admin operations, so you might want to re-create it:

```
createdb --maintenance-db=template1 -T template0 postgres;
```

What that's doing is connecting to the built-in DB `template1` in order to create the db `postgres` by making a copy of `template0`.

Once that's done, your command:

```
createdb mydbname;
```

will work as normal.

Comment: This is giving following error `createdb: illegal option -- d
Try "createdb --help" for more information.
`

Comment: Then I change the parameter -d to -D. After that it gave another error like follows `createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLESPACE" at character 26`

Comment: I edit your command like follows `createdb -T template1 postgres;` it mean change the `-d` to `-D`. Then my issue is fixed. Was that the the command you wanted to execute?

Comment: Can you change it to `-T`. The solution is working fine. then I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: if you change `-D` to `-T` on the answer I can make it as green. It will be useful to others.

Comment: @guru Weird, it actually shouldn't have. The corrected one shown now should though.

Answer (score 1):

`su - postgres`   change user to postgres 
`psql` - run psql terminal 
`postgres# create database somedatabase` create database;
`postgres#\c somedatabase`  connecto to database 
`somedatabase#` your are connected to that database as postgres user

Comment: Here also second command `psql` give error like follows (`psql: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist`)

Comment: did you start the server? `sudo service postgresql start` or alike

Comment: It is already running. Even I can use other already existing DB's.

Comment: psql -U postgres -d existingdb (will connect to terminal with user postgres and with), and then run create database newdb. It seems that postgres database is erased!!???. I assume you didn't erase it.

Comment: run `psql -U postgres -l` to list all the databases. You should have postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

```
su - postgres change user to postgres
createdb
createdb somedatabase
psql somedatabase
```

The first line changes to the postgres system user.  The second line creates a database for the postgres admin user.  The third line creates the database you were trying to make.  The fourth line connects to it as the postgres user.